# Moved Module from localhost to server, block type invalid

Tags: magento-1, blocks

I know that a lot of similiar questions has already been asked, but none of provided solutions worked for me, so i decided to add this question.

I have created new block for getting products by id's, and send them via ajax. As i developed it on my local machine, everything was perfect. Then, i decided to migrate changes to staging server. Normally, when i go to http://localhost/example/pl/ajaxloader i get JSON with product's html.
Now, after migrating, when i go to
https://example.com/pl/ajaxloader i get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on boolean in /home/klient.dhosting.pl/example.com/public_html/app/code/local/Projects/Ajaxloader/controllers/IndexController.php on line 39

I found our that my exception.log gives something like this:

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Projects_Ajaxloader_Block_Ajaxloader' in /home/klient.dhosting.pl/jett/example.com/public_html/app/Mage.php:595

Yet still i don't know how to make it work.

Here's my /app/etc/modules/projects_Ajaxloader.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
    <modules>
     <Projects_Ajaxloader>
       <active>true</active>
       <codePool>local</codePool>
     </Projects_Ajaxloader>
    </modules>
   </config>
```

And My /app/code/local/Projects/Ajaxloader/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
 <modules>
     <Projects_AjaxLoader>
         <version>0.1.0</version>
     </Projects_AjaxLoader>
 </modules>
 <frontend>
     <routers>
         <ajaxloader>
             <use>standard</use>
             <args>
                 <module>Projects_Ajaxloader</module>
                 <frontName>ajaxloader</frontName>
             </args>
         </ajaxloader>
     </routers>
     <layout>
         <updates>
             <ajaxloader module="Projects_Ajaxloader">
                 <file>Projects_Ajaxloader.xml</file>
             </ajaxloader>
         </updates>
     </layout>
 </frontend>
 <global>
     <blocks>
         <ajaxloader>
             <class>Projects_Ajaxloader_Block</class>
         </ajaxloader>
     </blocks>
 </global>
</config>
```

My `/app/code/local/Projects/Ajaxloader/block/Ajaxloader.php`

```
   <?php
      class Projects_AjaxLoader_Block_AjaxLoader extends Mage_Core_Block_Template { 
      }
```

My `/app/code/local/Projects/Ajaxloader/controllers/indexController.php`

```
    class Projects_Ajaxloader_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
       {

    public function indexAction()
    {

        // $url = $this->getRequest()->getPost('url');
        $product_ids = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
        $_productCollection = array();


        $itemsStart = $this->getRequest()->getPost('itemsCount');
        $itemsEnd = $itemsStart + 12;
        $showLoader = false;
        $this->loadLayout();
        $layout = $this->getLayout();


        // build an array for conversion
        $json_products = array();
        $i = 0;

        $block = $layout->getBlock("hello")->setData('product', $_product);
          //and other logic , but here's where the error happens

    }


}
```

and my `/app/design/frontend/rwd/example/layout/Projects_Ajaxloader.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <layout version="0.1.0">
      <ajaxloader_index_index>
          <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
           </action>
        </reference>
         <reference name="content">
            <block type="ajaxloader/ajaxloader" name="hello" template="ajaxloader/ajaxloader.phtml"/>
          </reference>
    </ajaxloader_index_index>
  </layout>
```

Comment: `$layout->getBlock("hello")` this code could not found your block.

Comment: Linux system are case sensitive try using this one /app/code/local/Projects/Ajaxloader/Block/ let us know if that doesn't work will try to help in other way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Double check uppercase & lowercase in folders, files & code (class names, for instance), as the examples you have pasted seem to be wrong

Comment: I don't think so... exception shows clearly Magento is not recognizing the module or it can't load some files... this is usually caused by Windows / Mac users, which are not familiar with case sensitive relevance in Unix servers

Comment: Sorry, It is my mistake. I have wrongly added a comment you post. thanks for the comment. I will remove it :)

Comment: Thank you guys, but changing block type from "ajaxloader/ajaxloader" to "core/template" fixed my problem. :)

Comment: Sure, but... did you understood why?

Comment: Yeah, i did. I've already switched from windows to ubuntu on my development machine.

Answer (score 0):

Changing "ajaxloader/ajaxloader" to "core/template" fixed the issue.